# stm32 freeRTOS UART Rx and Tx with DMA echo in Task

Tags: c, stm32, uart, dma

I'm trying to do a kind of "terminal" interaction with my STM32L476.
First of all I want to do a direct echo, when I recive data send it back for the same UART.
After, I want to put the echo in a task.

Question:
I'm implementing a hard-real time OS and want to leave UART operations to IDLE task, or very low priority task. 
Is this a good way of doing things?

I can print using:

`void uartPrint(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, char _out[]){
    HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(huart, (uint8_t *) _out, strlen(_out));
}`

But I don't receive, or the `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback`is not called never.

main.c

```
/
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32l4xx_hal.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"
#include "dma.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "spi.h"
#include "tim.h"
#include "gpio.h"

#include "display.h"

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;
UART_HandleTypeDef hlpuart1;

uint8_t rxData;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
void MX_FREERTOS_Init(void);

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_LPUART1_UART_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  MX_TIM15_Init();

  MX_FREERTOS_Init();

  osKernelStart();

    while (1){

    }

}

/** System Clock Configuration*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit;

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 20;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_LPUART1;
  PeriphClkInit.Lpuart1ClockSelection = RCC_LPUART1CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 15, 0);
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  if (htim->Instance == TIM1) {
    HAL_IncTick();
  }
}

void _Error_Handler(char * file, int line)
{
    while(1)
    {
    }
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{

}

#endif
```

usart.c

```
#include "usart.h"

#include "gpio.h"
#include "dma.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
#include "cmsis_os.h"
#include "string.h"

uint8_t Uart1RxBuf [UART3_RX_TRAMA_LONG];
uint8_t RxBuffer;
uint8_t rxData;
/* USER CODE END 0 */

UART_HandleTypeDef hlpuart1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_lpuart_rx;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_lpuart_tx;

/* LPUART1 init function */

void MX_LPUART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  hlpuart1.Instance = LPUART1;
  hlpuart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  hlpuart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  hlpuart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  hlpuart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  hlpuart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  hlpuart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  hlpuart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  hlpuart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&hlpuart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* uartHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(uartHandle->Instance==LPUART1)
  {
    __HAL_RCC_LPUART1_CLK_ENABLE();
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF8_LPUART1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    hdma_lpuart_rx.Instance = DMA2_Channel7;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_4;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_lpuart_rx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(uartHandle,hdmarx,hdma_lpuart_rx);

    /* LPUART_TX Init */
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Instance = DMA2_Channel6;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_4;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_lpuart_tx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(uartHandle,hdmatx,hdma_lpuart_tx);

    /* LPUART1 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(LPUART1_IRQn, 5, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(LPUART1_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_MspInit 1 */
        uartTaskStatus = INIT;

        HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&hlpuart1,&rxData,1);
  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_MspInit 1 */
  }
}

void HAL_UART_MspDeInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* uartHandle)
{

  if(uartHandle->Instance==LPUART1)
  {
    __HAL_RCC_LPUART1_CLK_DISABLE();
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1);
    HAL_DMA_DeInit(uartHandle->hdmarx);
    HAL_DMA_DeInit(uartHandle->hdmatx);
    HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(LPUART1_IRQn);

  }
} 

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *UartHandle)
{
    if(UartHandle -> Instance == hlpuart1.Instance){
        HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&hlpuart1,&rxData,1);
    }
}

void uartPrint(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, char _out[]){
    HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(huart, (uint8_t *) _out, strlen(_out));
}

void UartTask(void const *argument){
    char inBuffer[8];
    for(;;){
        switch(uartTaskStatus){
        case ERR:
            break;
        case INIT:
            uartPrint(&hlpuart1,"Uart Init: \r\n");
            uartTaskStatus = READ;
            break;
        case READ:
            break;
        }
        osDelay(100);
    }
}
```

I'm not using yet the uart task, but here is where I create the task at freertos.c

```
osThreadDef(uartTask, UartTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
uartTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(uartTask), NULL);
```

The `Uart Init:` appears on my terminal.

When I debug, program never reaches the `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback`.

Thanks!

EDIT 1:

DMA init!

```
void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
{
  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel5_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn);
  /* DMA2_Channel6_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Channel6_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Channel6_IRQn);
  /* DMA2_Channel7_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Channel7_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Channel7_IRQn);

}
```

Comment: 'osDelay(100);' what is that?  Looks like a fail to me:(

Comment: `osKernelStart()` should be used after you create your task and this call never returns, so it is useless to put an infinite loop after that call.

Comment: osDelay(100) makes task to execute as fast as 10 times per second, this is working for another task i have running that blinks a led. osKernelStart() is OK, I have other task moving leds and a LCD that are OK. I haven't copy all the freertos.c because is not useful for this question

Comment: the osDelay(100) is there because I don't think that I need to run this task more than 10 times per second, because is more or less the velocity of keyboard typing. I will change this number in order to not lose characters, but, dosen't DMA avoid loosing characters?

Comment: but it should not be archived by delays. What is the **hard**-real-time OS and what are differences between it and "normal" and **soft** real time OS-es?

Comment: Ok, delay is eliminated and continues not working. Hard-Real-Time is that i have to capture some signals and send other signals in very specific times, but this is not what I want to focus. What I want is to rx and tx uart using dma, disturbing the main functionality as much as possible.

Comment: DMA disturbing main functionality? Anyway. DMA for the echo (1 byte chunks) is an overkill. Just use the interrupts

Comment: But interrupts, can interrupt while acquiring, and add "time variation" to my data. The goal of doing with DMA( I'm with you that is overkilling) is to never interrupt the main task and not loose any character.

Comment: Is the DMA's interrupt enabled? Wich priority does it have? I have the same priority for USART's interrupt and for DMA's interrupt.

Comment: JMA, yes DMA interupt is enable or I think so, maybe I'm missing something. I EDIT the question adding the DMA init, is this what you mean?

Comment: we did not get DMA with interrupt worked either, we are using DMA with polling for RX.